# angularjs login before loading side menu template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have build an ionic side menu template app. Now I want to implement a login form which should only appear at first if there are no login credential saved in a sqlite database.

I did it with loading the login template first and then check in the controller of the login template if there are credential saved in the database and if so I redirect to the main side-menu page. But I didn't like this solution because it first loads the login screen for some frames even if there are credentials saved.

So how to do it the right angularjs/ionic way?

I think I have to handle the case that there are credentials saved in the config.js at the state provider. For the database calls I have implemented a factory.

My config.js looks like this:

```
.state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
...
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a default route that checks to see if the user is authorized using `ui-router` resolve capabilities... if the resolve fails then show the login router otherwise just continue in the app.

Comment: Can you please show me an example on how to do this in the router? I've made a workaround with a default start page. In this controller of the default start page I check for login credentials. I still think that this is not the right way to do it.